# SQL Query issue- Runs perfectly fine on Master database but fails while running it on other database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to identify the issue causing the below SQL query to fail with error ‘Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow on the line *`[DATEADD(d, 1, T1.TERM_DT)]`*(Table contain many records which are having Term date '12/31/9999' and range of datetime datatype is from '1000-01-01’ and ‘12/31/9999’).’
Below query runs perfectly fine when I run it on  master database. Query only fails with overflow error while running it on other Database on same server.
On other database , SQL doesn’t consider the condition *[TERM_DT < convert(datetime,'12/31/9999')]* which is causing it to overflow. Seems like some setting issue on other database, but let me know if anyone identifies what needs to be fixed.  Appreciate any input on this issue

```
 SELECT    T1.PFX,
          T1.ID,
          DATEADD(d, 1, T1.TERM_DT),
          DATEADD(d, -1, T2.EFF_DT),
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  PARTITION BY PFX,ID
                                   ORDER BY EFF_DT)AS 'ROWNUM',
                                   PFX,
                                   ID,
                                   EFF_DT,
                                   TERM_DT,                                   
       FROM [Database].dbo.Table1
       WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, EFF_DT, TERM_DT) NOT IN (0,1) 
     ) AS T1
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (    PARTITION BY PFX,ID
                                                      ORDER BY EFF_DT)AS 'ROWNUM',
                                                      PFX,
                                                      ID,
                                                      EFF_DT,
                                                      TERM_DT,
                                                      ID
                                  FROM [Database].dbo.Table1
                                  WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, EFF_DT, TERM_DT) NOT IN (0,1)
                                  ) AS T2
        ON   T1.PFX = T2.PFX
        AND  T1.ID = T2.ID
        AND  T1.ROWNUM + 1 = T2.ROWNUM
WHERE DATEADD(d, 1, T1.TERM_DT) <> T2.EFF_DT  and T1.TERM_DT < convert(datetime,'12/31/9999')
```

Comment: Please share the table structure with data. Also the query itself has errors. Please correct them as well

Comment: There is no specific order of execution of the conditions from your WHERE, so the engine can't know that you want to filter *first* by datetimes lower than 12/31/9999 and *then* add 1 day to the other comparison. In this case and for a particular execution plan, it's trying to add 1 day first, to solve the first comparison and fails.

Comment: To solve this, use a CTE or a subquery to filter the dates lower than 12/31/9999 and, in an outer scope, add 1 day for the other condition.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it runs fine in master. When a different query plan is used (which SQL picks when it thinks it will run faster), then it won't run anymore. You need to debug the failing query and forget about the one running correctly in master because that is just temporary luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this using `case`:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN T1.TERM_DT < '9999-12-31'
            THEN DATEADD(day, 1, T1.TERM_DT)
       END) <> T2.EFF_DT
```

Controlling the order of execution is the only "good" reason (that I can readily think of) for using a `CASE` expression in a `WHERE` clause.

Alternatively, you can change the logic to:

```
WHERE T1.TERM_DT = DATEADD(day, -1, T2.EFF_DT)
```